# Safari doesn't save google search results in history

Tags: macos, safari, catalina

macOS Catalina 10.15.2, maybe other versions:

1. Open a new tab in Safari
2. Use the omnibar to search for something
3. Open one of the google results
4. Press the browser back button (or cmd-[)

Observe: get taken to the new tab page, instead of to the google results page.

Additionally open history (cmd-y) the google results pages are never saved here.

How can I make it so that after visiting a Google result, I can still get back to the Google results page?

Comment: Only Google does it. other search engines don't.

Comment: Is this caused by opening youtube directly from Google search results?